# How can I quickly level my crops?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I'm playing the regrowth mod pack right now, and I'm working to get better seeds. Normally, in packs using AgriCraft, I use a setup like this with the watering can:

[image: Typical crop leveling system]

Which will very quickly cause the seeds to spread and create better versions very quickly, using a random but rounded-up average of the results, typically. This works well if you have a watering can, but this pack doesn't have Extra Utilities, so I don't have a watering can to increase growth ticks.

How can I quickly or at least easily level my crops?

Comment: Oh, is it another stolen IC2's idea? How sad... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no easy ways to increase the growth ticks in Regrowth, until mid/end game. So as a result upgrading crops takes time. This setup is for afk-ing, allowing the player to leave for a decent period of time and come back later to get the results.

Specifically in this pack weeds are disabled so you will not have to worry about them overrunning.

Using a setup that only allows crops to spread to one adjacent tile, it is easy to find the crop with the highest stat.

Setup:

```
S: Soil O: Other W: Water
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _
|S|O|S|S|S|O|S|
|S|O|S|O|S|O|S|
|S|O|S|O|S|O|S|
|S|O|S|O|S|O|S|
|S|O|S|W|S|O|S|
|S|O|S|O|S|O|S|
|S|O|S|O|S|O|S|
|S|O|S|O|S|O|S|
|S|S|S|O|S|S|S|
```

This is infinitely expandable, just increase the length or the number of the lines. Later in the pack you can have multiple farms going at once to max out your seeds much quicker.

Source: [Direwolf20's Regrowth Series](https://youtu.be/HLMNgj0hF50?t=3m25s)

Comment: Doesn't AgriCraft have a weed mechanic where empty crop sticks will grow weeds?

Comment: Disabled in the pack

Comment: Oh, sweet, that makes everything easier.

Comment: @ModDL I know this is an old answer, but if you have a link to the youtube video you could include it in your source.

Answer (score 1):

Best way I've found is to make a square 6x6 or bigger of double crops, plant your seed in one corner, and let it spread all the way across to the opposite corner, by the time it gets there it should have jumped a handful of levels. A 111 seed should easily be close to 555 or better by the other end. It's best to analyze all the seeds on the far edge though incase the highest genome seed wasn't the first to reach the end.

As for speeding this up water channels and sprinklers work well once you have iron. Also try and do your mutation breeding with 10-10-10 stock as that will give you a resulting 5-5-5 seed to level up with.

For example: LVL 10-10-10 wheat + LVL 10-10-10 melon would give LVL 5-5-5 mystical white seed instead of the usual 1-1-1 you'd get from mutating with 1-1-1 seeds. Starting with 5-5-5 makes further leveling much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use only one mature seed against the double crop sticks and if you have a altar use ritual of growth or something like that and  growth sigal

Comment: Also you can hand install mods in hqm modpacks with no side effects.

Comment: So just add Extra Utilities to the modpack